# Using arithmetic expression in SET for UPDATE

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I want to multiply a value from a selected column in an update subquery and get a new value, like this:

new `A.GROSS` value would be `A.GROSS` from TAO multiplied by the selected `B.PERCENT_VALUE` from SPLIT file

I tried like below:

```
UPDATE PS_HR_TAO10 A SET A.GROSS = (A.GROSS_AMT * B.PERCENT_VALUE) 
(SELECT B.PERCENT_VALUE FROM PS_Z_NEW_FY_SPLIT B
WHERE A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID)
WHERE A.PAY_END_DT = '09-JUL-2016';
```

Comment: This is the SQL that worked:
update PS_HR_TAO10 A 
set  A.GROSS_AMT = (Select A.GROSS_AMT * B.PERCENT_VALUE
                from PS_Z_NEW_FY_SPLIT B
                where  A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID)
where A.PAY_END_DT = TO_DATE('09-JUL-2016', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
and EXISTS
(Select A.GROSS_AMT * B.PERCENT_VALUE
                from PS_Z_NEW_FY_SPLIT B
                where  A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID);

Answer (score 0):

I would go for merge statement:

```
merge into PS_HR_TAO10 A
using (select EMPLID, PERCENT_VALUE from PS_Z_NEW_FY_SPLIT) B
on (A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID)
when matched then update set
A.GROSS = A.GROSS_AMT * B.PERCENT_VALUE
WHERE A.PAY_END_DT = '09-JUL-2016';
```

Comment: Again..Same ...but this time you were faster :-) . I delete mine,

Comment: @XING yeah we're just looking on the same questions. Don't worry I'm leaving soon ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I get ""Statement not valid. Start Line 1. End Line 6.Error in Script File. Start Line 1. End Line 6" I executing this as SQL, not as a script.

Comment: please try now.